# Authguard Angular2-Metoer application with promise

Tags: angular, meteor, promise, angular2-routing, angular-meteor

I am working on a `Angular2-Meteor` application and I started this application from the scratch. So there are two panels, `admin` and `client`, So I create authguard for it. But I think that my code is not good enough. 
So that how my authguard works:

```
canActivate = () => {
        if(Meteor.userId()) {
            if(!Meteor.user()) {
                var timeOutReturnValue = new Promise((resolve) => {
                    var MeteorUserFinder = Meteor.setInterval(() => {
                        if(Meteor.user()){
                            var admin = Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'admin');
                            var employee = Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'employee');
                            if(admin){
                                Meteor.clearTimeout(MeteorUserFinder);
                                resolve({status: Boolean(false), role: 'admin'});
                            }
                            else if(employee){
                                Meteor.clearTimeout(MeteorUserFinder);
                                resolve({status: Boolean(false), role: 'employee'});
                            }
                        }
                        return
                    }, 10);
                });
                return timeOutReturnValue.then((value) => {
                    if(value.role == 'admin'){
                        this.router.navigate(['/admin/dashboard']);
                    }
                    else if(value.role == 'employee') {
                        this.router.navigate(['/client']);
                    }
                    return Boolean(value.status);
                });
            }
            else if(Meteor.user()) {
                var admin = Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'admin');
                var employee = Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'employee');
                if(admin) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/admin/dashboard']);
                    return false;
                }
                else if(employee) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/client']);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
            return false;
        }
    };
```

So at the start I used canActivate function function which returns boolean value true or false it depends for which panel this authguard is creating. 
So the main problem is that `Meteor.user` is responding late so that's why I have to use `Promise` and `setInterval`. I need you guys to help me with that. How can I make it smooth and is there any other possible way to do this?

> **Note** : This authguard is just a sample and it is using in the main app
>   to route the where a user have to go.

Comment: At least say what is the issue.

Comment: The first issue is that I am using `setInterval` and `promise` both. It have too many conditions and the code is too long. I need this code to be small and perfect.

Comment: Does it looks good? I made it more complex. Can you understand it?